# Bash ampersand prevention

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a problem.
I tried many options how to prevent my parameter from escaping with "&" character.
Nothing works for unfortunately.
Do You have any option how to prevent my string and allow only [a-z]??
I tried everything on stack overflow and still nothing.

That's the script example:

```
#!/bin/bash/
initials=$1

initials_buffer(){
    if [[ ${#initials} -ge 5 ]] ; then echo "Error: Bad initials. Too long!!!" ; exit 0
    elif [[ ${#initials} -le 3 ]] ; then echo "Error: Bad initials. Too short!!!" ; exit 0
    elif [[ $initials == *['!'@#\$%^\&*()_+]* ]] ; then echo "Hey!! No special chars" ; exit 0
    else 
        echo "properly string"
    fi
}

initials_buffer
exit 0
```

And that's results where i have too short, too long and i escaped from script to whoami command as a root.

```
    ┌──(rootkali)-[/]
└─# bash test.sh pr            
Error: Bad initials. Too short!!!
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(rootkali)-[/]
└─# bash test.sh praaaaaa      
Error: Bad initials. Too long!!!
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(rootkali)-[/]
└─# bash test.sh pr*n    
Hey!! No special chars
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
┌──(rootkali)-[/]
└─# bash test.sh pra& whoami   
[1] 7951
root
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Error: Bad initials. Too short!!!
[1]  + done       bash test.sh pra
```

Every char prevention is working except "&", "(" and ")"..

Comment: Quote the argument. `bash test.sh "pra& whoami"`

Comment: `bash test.sh pra& whoami` runs `bash test.sh pra` in the background, and then runs `whoami` in the foreground. It does **not** pass `&` to `test.sh`, so there's nothing `test.sh` could possibly do to reject it.

Comment: Similarly, `bash test.sh pr*n` doesn't always pass `pr*n` as an argument to `test.sh` -- if you're in a directory that has files `prawn` and `priwn` in it, those filenames will be passed as arguments instead, _and nothing your script can do can change that_ because it happens before the script even starts. It's the responsibility of the user **calling** your script to write correct shell syntax for their calls, and in this case that means quoting: `bash test.sh 'pra&'` and `bash test.sh 'pr*wn'`

Comment: (I'm assuming from the `.exe` in your username that you come from Windows -- while on Windows command-line parsing from a string to an argument vector is done by the libc in the program that was invoked and can be overridden, on UNIX programs are invoked with an argument vector directly; they never get a chance to see the original string).

Comment: Thank You Charles! Thank You for answer that it is impossible. I need to do a script where i can't trust people. So i will need to write this script in other language.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to match edge cases that are invalid, it seems easier to match the valid cases.  If you want a string of 3 to 5 characters between a and z, just match it explicitly:

```
if ! [[ $initials =~ [a-z]{3,5} ]]; then
        echo "Error: Bad initials.  Must be 3 to 5 characters a-z" >&2
        exit 1
fi
```

Also, write your error messages to stderr, and exit with a reasonable value.

Comment: This is correct as far as it goes, but it doesn't help the user understand why `bash test.sh pra&` isn't passing `"pra&"` as `$1`.

Comment: I tried Williams Method but still is not working
Result:                                                                                        
┌──(rootkali)-[/opt/P01162-ScanGrid]
└─# bash test.sh ars& whoami
[1] 9813
root
Hey!!
[1]  + done       bash test.sh ars

Comment: I just need to create unhackable script sudo wrappper with no option to get out from string by adding &. :(

Comment: @przem.exe `bash test.sh ars&` executes the script `test.sh` (a terrible name!) with the single argument `ars`.